# awk strip line breaks from result

Tags: awk

Ive a simple awk function like this:

```
awk '/ALPHA/ {print} /BETA/,/GAMMA/ {print}' file
```

and it prints 2 matches, the first from matching the row with 'ALPHA' and the second as range between 'BETA' and 'GAMMA'. Since the range output includes line breaks and I want in a single row Ive tried:

```
awk '/FIRST/ {print} /SECOND/,/THIRD/ {gsub(/\n/," "); print}' file
```

But its having no effect. How can I get rid of line breaks from the second match?

Comment: ok, replace {gsub(/\n/," ") with {printf("%s ", $0)}

Comment: [edit] your question to include concise,testable sample input and expected output and someone will help you. The correct answer will be clear and simple and will not involve a range expression. And, obviously, don't change your example from alpha, beta, gamma to first, second, and third mid-question! "I have 3 questions - 1, 2, and c...".

Answer (score 1):

The `print` in your final code introduces a newline for each printed line.

You will have to output the lines with `printf("%s ", $0)` (the `gsub` is not needed).

However, this will cause problems when exiting the range as there's now no newline in the output.  Therefore, you can add an extra block to output that newline (after `/SECOND/,/THIRD/ {...}`):

```
/THIRD/ { printf("\n") }
```

This will however cause spurious newlines to be included in the output if you have lines matching `/THIRD/` with no corresponding lines matching `/SECOND/` earlier.

Answer (score 0):

Ive a solution that works:

```
'awk '/FIRST/ {print} /SECOND/,/THIRD/  {gsub(/ /, "", $0); printf("%s ", $0)}' file
```

This removes all extra white spaces as well as line breaks

Comment: That will add a blank to the end of every "THIRD" line and will produce a non-text file if THIRD is the last line of the file. Don't do it.